# Storing data in a doubly linked list

Tags: c++, function, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I need to create a doubly linked list that stores different types of data.

I can’t enter a few words through the console through space in one line so that they are written in one variable. I tried to use `cin.getline(book.plant, 50);` but it doesn`t work correctly.

And I cannot make a delete function. I want to make a function that deletes the line in which the first element is equal to the one I enter.  Each time I run the code, it displays to me: there is no such element.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <locale>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <list>

using namespace std;
typedef struct  // создание узла двусвязного списка
{
    char plant[50];
    char family[50];
    char species[50];  //вид
    char sort[50];     //род
    char purpose[50];   //призначення
    char territory[50];    //територія зростання
    //char map[50];       // карта обліку
    char compatibility[50];   //сумістність зіншими видами
}BOOK;

typedef struct tag_obj 
{
    BOOK b;
    struct tag_obj* prev, * next;
}OBJ;

OBJ* head = NULL, * tail = NULL;

void add_obj(OBJ* obj, BOOK book) {

    OBJ* ptr = new OBJ;

    ptr->b = book;
    ptr->prev = obj;
    ptr->next = (obj == NULL) ? NULL : obj->next;

    if (obj != NULL) {
        obj->next = ptr;
        if (obj->next != NULL) obj->next->prev = ptr;
    }
    if (ptr->prev == NULL) head = ptr;
    if (ptr->next == NULL) tail = ptr;
}

void del_obj(OBJ* obj) {
    char x[50];
    cout << "enter the name of the plant whose data you want to delete: ";
    cin >> x;
    OBJ* tmp;
    OBJ* h;

    if (head == NULL) // емли нет не одного узла, то возращаемся
    {
        cout << "List empty,nothing to delete" << endl;
        return;
    }
    if (head->b.plant == x)     //удаляем первый елемент
    {
        tmp = head;
        head = head->next;  // теперь голова -это следующий елемент
        head->prev = NULL;   // предыдущего не существует
        cout << "Element Deleted" << endl;
        free(tmp);
        return;
    }
    h = head;
    while (h->next->next != NULL)
    {

        if (h->next->b.plant == x)    // удаляем елемент после
        {
            tmp = h->next;
            h->next = tmp->next;
            tmp->next->prev = h;
            cout << "Element Deleted" << endl;
            free(tmp);
            return;
        }
        h = h->next;
    }
    if (h->next->b.plant == x) // удаление последнего елемента
    {
        tmp = h->next;
        free(tmp);
        h->next = NULL;      //следующего не существует
        cout << "Element Deleted" << endl;
        return;
    }
    cout << "Element " << x << " not found" << endl;



}


void show() {
    OBJ* c = head;
    while (c != NULL) {
        cout << c->b.plant << "  " << c->b.family << "  " << c->b.species << "  " << c->b.sort << "  " << c->b.purpose << "  " << c->b.territory << "  " << c->b.compatibility << endl ;
        c = c->next;
    }
}


int main() {
    //setlocale(LC_ALL, "ukr");
   BOOK book = { " PLANT  ","  FAMILY  "  };
    //add_obj(tail, book);


    int choice;
    char x;
    cout << "**plant account**" << endl;
    cout << "1(add an element to the beginning)" << endl;
    cout << "2(add an element to the end)" << endl;
    cout << "3(delete)" << endl;
    cout << "4(show)" << endl;
    cout << "6(exit)" << endl << endl;
    while (222)
    {                             
        cout << " Choose action : ";
        cin >> choice;
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            cout << "Plant name: ";
            cin >> book.plant;
            cout << "Plant family: ";
            cin >> book.family;
            cout << "Plant species: ";
            cin >> book.species;
            cout << "Plant sort: ";
            cin >> book.sort;
            cout << "Purpose of the plant: ";
            cin >> book.purpose;
            cout << "Growth area: ";
            cin >> book.territory;
            cout << "Compatibility with other species: ";
            cin >> book.compatibility;
            add_obj(head, book);
            cout << endl;
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "Plant name: ";
            cin >> book.plant;
            cout << "Plant family: ";
            cin >> book.family;
            cout << "Plant species: ";
            cin >> book.species;
            cout << "Plant sort: ";
            cin >> book.sort;
            cout << "Purpose of the plant: ";
            cin >> book.purpose;
            cout << "Growth area: ";
            cin >> book.territory;
            cout << "Compatibility with other species: ";
            cin >> book.compatibility;
            add_obj(tail, book);
            cout << endl;
            break;
        case 3:
            del_obj(head);
            cout << endl;
            break;
        case 4:
            show();
            cout << endl;
            break;
        case 5:
            cout << " " << endl;
            exit(222);
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You cannot compare C-style strings with `==`.  Try using `std::string` instead (throughout).

Comment: use `strcmp()` to compare C-style strings

Comment: When using `==` on C-style strings, you are not comparing the actual string contents, but only the pointers (i.e. addresses) to these strings. This is not what you want. See the comments above for alternatives (`std::string` and `strcmp`).

Comment: `strncmp()` is better.

Comment: It looks like you could simplify the `main` function for this [mre]. You could take out the menu system and instead add a (hardcoded) plant to the list followed by an attempt to remove that same plant. *(Focusing on just the "find" functionality would be even better, but your code is not modular enough to do that easily.)*

Comment: BTW, in C++ you don't need the `typedef struct`, you can cut it down to `struct`.

Comment: I recommend adding an input method to your structure, so you don't repeat code.